# Mysql 5.7 - CentOS Init error : initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting

Tags: mysql, centos

I'm having an issue with my MySQL 5.7 install on CentOS 7.

When I'm trying to start the service:

> initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting

Which is weird because it's empty:

my.cnf:

```
tmpdir                         = /home5/mysql/MYP015RANB/tmp
datadir                        = /home4/mysql/MYP015RANB/data
```

/home4 is empty.

I already tried to delete my instance / remove MySQL / reinstall everything.

Any ideas?

Comment: 1. Have you tried completely purging `/home4`? 
2. Can you add the series of commands you used to get to this point, i.e. how you installed and tried to start everything up?

Comment: @AaronMeese
cd /home4
rm -rf mysql
service rh-mysql57-mysqld@MYP015RANB start